# Rest Framework serializer with support for multiple depths

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer class that looks like this:

```
class ShipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shipment
        depth = 1
```

The shipment model has a foreign key to another model `Location`, referred to as `receiver`. Currently I can POST a nested object like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"receiver": {"name": "Bob", "phone": "555-555-5555"}' http://localhost:8000/api/shipments/
```

But I also need to be able to do a flat POST, referring to the pk of the receiver. Similar to having depth=0:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"receiver": 43}' http://localhost:8000/api/shipments/
```

What is the best approach to support both types of POSTs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having two serializers. The serializer class that will be used can be determined at runtime by overriding the *get_serializer_class* . Example:

```
get_serializer_class(self): 
    receiver = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('receiver', None)
    if receiver not None:
        try:
            int(receiver)
            return ... # serializer with depth 0
        except ValueError:
            return ... # depth 1 serializer
```

Hope this helps.